# Codeigniter A PHP Error was encountered, Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3.0.0 and have just tested the program live online. The website is www.theloven.com. 
The problem is like below 
I could not fix the error.I need some help on this case 
**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (42000/1203): User ... already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

File: /home/.../public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/theloven8/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 140

Backtrace:

File: /home/.../public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/theloven8/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 168

Backtrace:

File: /home/.../public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: Are you closing the mysql connections after each query?

Comment: I am new to this and don;t know where to check.

Answer (score 1):

First you have specify local host user name and passwords in config > database.php

1. 'hostname' => 'localhost',
   'username' => 'uname',
   'password' => 'password',
   'database' => 'project',
   'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',